# Problem with repeating program in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i get this program repeat when 'again' gets 'Y' or 'y'? Yesterday the same code worked smh, but today it closes the program whatever i write in there) And yeah...tabulation is wrong but it's because stackoverflow copied it in some weird way :))

```
while True:   
    start = input("What do you want to do? + - * /  ")
    if start == '+':
        x = float(input("digit 1  "))   
        y = float(input("digit 2  "))
        res = x + y
        print('The result is ' + str(res))
    again = input('Do u want to try again? Y/N ')
    if again == 'N' or 'n':
        break
```

Comment: please format your code from now on while asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you are using the wrong syntax for checking the condition. Use this syntax :

```
if again=='N' or again=='n':
    break
```

Comment: Sweet!Thanks friend! :)